# Get current time in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In the "update" function, in the SKScene class, there's a parameter called "currentTime".

The documentation describes it as following:

```
 //@param currentTime the current time in the app. This must be monotonically increasing.
```

Is there a way for me to get this value in "didMoveToView"?

Comment: it only starts updating after moving to view. Why do you need that inside didMoveToView?

Comment: So I can keep track of when the game started. I can of course have some condition check to see if the value has been initialized, and if not set the value in update, but that seems kinda hacky. Setting it in didMoveToView would be more elegant.

Comment: All you need is to store the NSDate moment (now) that the game started and use timeIntervalSinceNow to calculate the elapsed time. I can post an example for you if you want

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, but I should be able to do it on my own. I was hoping to use current time, because, again, it seems kinda hacky to use NSDate when you already have a time argument. Are you sure there isn't a way to get it in didMoveToView?

Comment: Like I said current time only exists after moving to view so it will not be available there when it gets executed

Comment: add those two vars to your game scene class; var startTime: NSDate! ; 
    var sceneCurrentTime: NSTimeInterval = 0. Inside your method update you just need sceneCurrentTime = abs(startTime.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)

Comment: inside didMoveToView add; startTime = NSDate()